# Quickly switching between access points using Netplan and NetworkManager

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, netplan, wireless-access-point

I am working on a mobile robot base that uses a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Server 22.04. It receives commands from a stationary server, so it must have a reliable connection to the network at all times. The building it's supposed to operate in has access points set up to cover most of the area with some overlapping coverage between access points.

If the robot is manually carried between access points it will connect to closer ones within a reasonable time. However, if it is moving from the coverage area of one access point towards another it will stop when it drops the wifi connection, and it will try to reassociate with the previous access point even if it is in the coverage area of another.
How can I make sure it tries to connect to the closest access point available to it?

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.

Comment: How's the AP's configured? Are they set up to support roaming?

Comment: I didn't find any mesh or roaming related settings on the access point. Isn't that controlled by the station instead of the AP?